# Rails 4 - Order by the presence of an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4. Psql DB.

I have a model `Article` with an attribute `amazon_title`. I am having trouble understanding how I can order my articles so articles with the `amazon_title` present are first, and ones without are second.

I've tried ordering them like this with no success:

```
Article.all.order(amazon_title: :desc)
```

The above orders it alphabetically, showing blank first, present second, and nil third.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: using psql @RSB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For PostgreSQL (the order will be `true`, `false`, `nil`):

```
Article.order('amazon_title DESC NULLS LAST')
```

Another option (database agnostic):

```
Article.order('(CASE WHEN amazon_title THEN 1 WHEN amazon_title IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 3 END) ASC')
```

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL you can pass `NULLS FIRST` OR `NULLS LAST` depending on your requirement. That's why I asked you about your DB.

```
Article.order('amazon_title DESC NULLS FIRST')
```

the above will list the NULLS first and

```
Article.order('amazon_title DESC NULLS LAST')
```

and this one will list the NULL records last.

Hope that helps!